# In the comics is Blade known to have a particular accent?

Tags: marvel, comics, blade

In the main Marvel comics continuity (Universe 616), Blade's background is that he was born and raised in Soho London, yet in all the other media (movies, live action TV show,  cartoons) I have seen him in, he is never portrayed with an English accent.

Admittedly his back story has been tweaked for his appearances in other media.

Now I understand you can't "hear" a comic, but in the main Marvel comics universe is it ever referenced that he has an English accent? or any recognisable accent at all?

I'd prefer answers to relate to comics taking place in the Marvel main 616 universe and answers relating to comics that take place in the same universes as movies, TV shows, games, etc are strictly out of scope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you say, Blade has gone through a few transformations and retcons and tweaks.  I'm going to cite his first ever appearance in *Tomb of Dracula* #10 (1973).  The slang and manner Blade is speaking sounds more like a comic book writer's idea of the "mean streets of America" than "south of London cockney" (or "BBC posh").

Also suggestive is his use of "wooden nickels", wooden nickels being a piece of [American historical slang](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/don%27t_take_any_wooden_nickels).

[image]

[image]